# Magento 1.6- Where did Order Archive section go?

Tags: orders, magento-1.6

I am looking into this guide:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/archiving-orders

However, I cant find **Order Archive section** anywhere in `Magento 1.6`...

Can anyone tell me where is it?

Answer (score 1):

The order archive is not available on Community Editions.
It's available on Enterprise Edition, and from the looks of the article you posted it's also available on Magento Go. There is a text below the title saying

> Platform: Magento Go

Comment: hmm ok. If it isnt bad enough that I have to work on Magento, now I have to remember all their keywords like "Go", "1.6", "CE", "Enterprise Edition" etc....!! and each having 1 million different unique issues...!!

Comment: I know it seams confusing at first, but you will get the hang of it.

Comment: ok, let see... :D